# Convert numerical dictionary to list with duplicates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A simple example:

What I have:

```
{10:1, 20:2, 30:3}
```

What I want:

```
[10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30]
```

Any idea of compressed coding in Python 3 without using loops?

Answer (score 4):

"Compressed coding"? Maybe with a `Counter` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

```
[*Counter(d).elements()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoMwEAbv@xQLvURR8edShF7axyg9BE0xkGRDshZK6bNbK1qw129ndvyTB3LN0Ydpugey2JExqmNNLqK2ngLjhUbHKgD0eMJXVbZVhnXZ1hk2Zdu8AeS8X9MVE31SKKOschxFcgMftGMhEwA45HmOZ3JjxEhmXCKwVPUsMpH5NbtBapdhUF5JzjCyDFb6LbVcRbquYqP6Yv5j52qy6@6cHf9VHtKM6s@Zpg8)

Answer (score 1):

Nice use of a "`dictionary comprehension`" here:

```
freq_data = {10:1, 20:2, 30:3}
result = [category for (category,count) in freq_data.items() for iteration in range(count)]

# or succinctly
result = [k for k,v in freq_data.items() for _ in range(v)]
```

here what we do is expand the dictionary by the key,value pairs then iterate the key for the length of range(v)

Answer (score 0):

Two liner from my side:

```
dict_t = {10:1, 20:2, 30:3}
list_result = [v*[k] for k,v in dict_t.items()]
list_final = flatten(list_result)
print(list_final)
```

Using the flatten function provided at this link.
[flatten function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

```
def flatten(t):
    return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
```

Result:

```
[10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dict_t = {10:1, 20:2, 30:3}
>>> print([i for s in [[k]*v for k,v in d.items()] for i in s])
[10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30]
```